# Java tool to perform a specific "Data Analysis" on ASM code

Tags: java, bytecode, data-analysis, java-bytecode-asm

I need a particular "Data Analysis" on ASM code using a Java Class or anything that can be used on Eclipse. Specifically i need identify three step on a variable with this order: 
1) Use;
2) Initialization;
3) Delete.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't `Use` a variable before `Initialization`. You can't `Delete` a variable.

If you want to analyse byte code I suggest using ObjectWeb's ASM library.

Comment: Thank for the answer. I misspelled, I mean literally analyze assembly code and find these passages intended as the eax register:
1) the result stored in the register
2) a new value stored in eax
3) reset eax

Comment: I don't know of any library for reading native assembly. In Java you can read the byte code before it is turned into native assembly.  BTW: 1) Almost every instruction stores a result in a register. 2) I assume eax is just an example and you are interested in all the general purpose registers. Do you want the floating point ones as well?  3) There is no "reset eax" machine instruction as such.